# Converting Fabric.js text to path

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I write some text on canvas with Fabric.js lib and with google fonts included. Then I export canvas to SVG through `toSvg()` function.

When I import `*.svg` file in the vector editor, e.g. Inkscape, the font become a default - Arial. Checking svg-file structure I do not identify any errors - it has proper font declaration.

So I have a question: how to convert `fabric.Text` to shape or path, to save it without issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I've been looking at solutions for this for a week now..

Comment: How about changing the font in Inkscape to the one you want, save as SVG and compare the file differences?...

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be possible with https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js now.